# overriding bool() for custom class

Tags: python, class, casting, boolean, python-2.x

All I want is for bool(myInstance) to return False (and for myInstance to evaluate to False when in a conditional like if/or/and. I know how to override >, <, =)

I've tried this:

```
class test:
    def __bool__(self):
        return False

myInst = test()
print bool(myInst) #prints "True"
print myInst.__bool__() #prints "False"
```

Any suggestions?

(I am using Python 2.6)

Answer (score 72, accepted):

Is this Python 2.x or Python 3.x?  For Python 2.x you are looking to override `__nonzero__` instead.

```
class test:
    def __nonzero__(self):
        return False
```

Comment: Thanks for this... I was looking for a way to test the `__nonzero__` class method for [testing `False` here](https://github.com/trinitronx/python_koans/commit/2fe356926fef8e615b06fe7aaaa9a844536e58b5)

Comment: It would be of benefit to mention that __bool__ is python3 and code to make a class more portable across python2/3 as mentioned by John below.

Answer (score 70):

If you want to keep your code forward compatible with python3 you could do something like this

```
class test:
    def __bool__(self):
        return False
    __nonzero__=__bool__
```

Comment: The __nonzero__=__bool__ seems to how an error in python 2 because __bool__ is not defined.

Comment: @LeoUfimtsev  have you moved "\_\_nonzero\_\_=\_\_bool\_\_" to a smaller line number than "def \_\_bool\_\_(self):" ? in that case it is undefined, written order matters here.

Comment: Wouldn't this create a class variable instead of an instance variable?

Answer (score 10):

If your `test` class is list-like, define `__len__` and `bool(myInstanceOfTest)` will return `True` if there are 1+ items (non-empty list) and `False` if there are 0 items (empty list). This worked for me.

```
class MinPriorityQueue(object):
    def __init__(self, iterable):
        self.priorityQueue = heapq.heapify(iterable)
    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.priorityQueue)

>>> bool(MinPriorityQueue([])
False
>>> bool(MinPriorityQueue([1,3,2])
True
```

Comment: That's handy. Thanks for this alternate solution.

Comment: This is actually the best solution as it is compatible with both Python3 and Python2 to my knowledge. Even if it is not an iterable you could implement something to mock it.

Answer (score 6):

Similar to John La Rooy, I use:

```
class Test(object):
    def __bool__(self):
        return False

    def __nonzero__(self):
        return self.__bool__()
```

Comment: `__nonzero__ = __bool__` is the preferable way of aliasing `__bool__` because it's less code (quicker to read, less to maintain), less likely to hide a bug (what happens if `__bool__` later becomes an async function?), but more importantly 1 less stack frame for a frequently called function that's also implicit! The difference here is whether you're defining 2 functions or just 1 function that's referenced twice.

Answer (score 4):

[`test.__nonzero__()`](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__nonzero__)

Comment: It is short and code only (with a link) but it does answer the question...

Answer (score 2):

[this is a comment to the answer from @john-la-rooy but I cannot comment yet :) ]

For Python3 compatibility you can do (I was looking for this)

```
class test(object):
    def __bool__(self):
        return False

    __nonzero__=__bool__
```

only problem is that you need to repeat the `__nonzero__ = __bool__` everytime you change `__bool__` in subclasses. Otherwise `__nonzero__` will be kept from the superclass. You can try

```
from builtins import object  # needs to be installed !

class test(object):
    def __bool__(self):
        return False

    __nonzero__=__bool__
```

which should work (not confirmed) or write a metaclass :) yourself.

Comment: Or use the approach from tknickman to avoid this issue. It will add another function call though!