# How to overload Python's __bool__ method in 2.x?

Tags: python, methods, overloading, python-2.x, magic-methods

I thought this should print "False", why is it printing "True"?

```
>>> class Foo(object):
...   def __bool__(self):
...     return False
... 
>>> f = Foo()
>>> if f:
...   print "True"
... else:
...   print "False"
... 
True
>>>
```

Comment: Dup of [overriding bool() for custom class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2233786)

Answer (score 100, accepted):

You should define `__nonzero__()` in Python 2.x.  It was only renamed to `__bool__()` in Python 3.x.  (The name `__nonzero__()` actually predates the introduction of the `bool` type by many years.)

Comment: It is strange that I could not find that information anywhere else but in your answer. Thanks a lot !

Comment: @MehmetKaanERKOÇ The documentation for most of the magic methods is on the [data model page of the Python reference](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html). Differences between Python 2 and 3 are mostly documented in the [What's New page of Python 3.0](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.0.html#operators-and-special-methods). I'll admit this is not easy to find if you don't know what you are looking for.