# What operation is called on A in "while A:"?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, while-loop, operation

Lets say I have:

```
class Bar:
    pass
A = Bar()

while A:
    print("Foo!")
```

What operation is then called on `A` in order to determine the `while` loop?

I've tried `__eq__` but that didn't do much.

Comment: I think A is a reference to an instance of Bar, and therefore not False.

Comment: `bool(A)` I think ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

User-defined objects are truthy, unless you define a custom `__bool__`:

```
>>> class A:
...     pass
...
>>> a = A()
>>> if a: print(1)
...
1
>>> class B:
...     def __bool__(self):
...         return False
...
>>> b = B()
>>> if b: print(1)
...
>>>
```

Comment: @richard - Failure to understand code is not an appropriate reason to edit it. These "confusing and irrelevent chevrons, elipses" are from an interactive interpreter session.

Comment: I have used ipython, as well. I have also seen my pupils type in the chevrons.

Comment: @richard - The question is explicitly tagged with Python 3, and contains a Python 3-style `print()` call (which technically works in Python 2, but is much more likely to appear in Python 3).

Comment: @richard - Also, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8909932/how-to-overload-pythons-bool-method.

Comment: There is nothing non python2 about that print call, and I put in the comment to help anyone that comes after me, not to start an argument.

Answer (score 2):

The [`while` statement](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-while-statement) is composed of the `while` keyword followed by an expression.

When an [expression is used in a control flow statement](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#boolean-operations) the truth value of that expression is evaluated by calling the objects `__bool__` method:

> In the context of Boolean operations, and *also when expressions are used by control flow statements*, the following values are interpreted as false: `False`, `None`, numeric zero of all types, and empty strings and containers (including strings, tuples, lists, dictionaries, sets and frozensets). *All other values are interpreted as true.* *User-defined objects can customize their truth value by providing a `__bool__()` method.*

In short, the result depends on what the `__bool__` of your object returns; since you haven't specified one, a default value of `True` is used.

Answer (score 1):

There are different methods, that can be called, to determine, whether an object evaluates to `True` or `False`.

If a `__bool__`-method is defined, this is called, otherwise, if `__len__` is defined, its result is compared to `0`.